Fixing the Initial Ad Mediation & Mobile Dependency Resolver in Unity for Android
If so, and if you're like me, you have been trying to find a way to fix this issue for a while. Luckily, I believe I finally found a fix (and I had been searching for a while even though the answer was right under my nose the entire time, apparently).
After digging through the guides on IronSource, I managed to find this section.
You would think this would be something that is mentioned at the beginning of the setup, but I stared at it thinking "no way it's that easy, right?" so I decided to try just that.
Go to Edit > Project Settings > Player > Publishing Settings, and check "Custom Main Gradle Template".
Screenshot of Project Settings > Player > Publishing Settings with the Custom Main Gradle Template section highlighted
The Mobile Dependency Resolver settings should have the Patch mainTemplate.gradle setting enabled by default, but make sure it is enabled just in case. You can access these settings by right-clicking in your project window and select Mobile Dependency Resolver > Android Resolver > Settings
You may have to close and re-open your Unity Project, but it should auto-resolve now. You can force resolve by right-clicking in your project window and selecting Mobile Dependency Resolver > Android Resolver > Force Resolve
I am posting this because I am not sure where else to post this, and I want to help save others the days of headaches trying to figurte this out. I hope this helps someone out there!
